# Elasticsearch cluster instances are showing up as an individual masters

Tags: elasticsearch, deployment, cluster-computing

I am trying to deploy a 2 node elasticsearch cluster.

**I have 2 VM's as follow:**

VM1 -> 10.20.1.4 (CentOS7)

VM2 -> 10.20.1.5 (CentOS7)

I have installed java8 as a prerequisite in both the above VM.

Downloaded the elasticsearch tar from below link:
https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/distribution/tar/elasticsearch/2.1.0/elasticsearch-2.1.0.tar.gz

**In VM1 (10.20.1.4), I have below configuration in elasticsearch.yml file**

```
cluster.name: TestCluster
node.name: "node1"
node.master: true
transport.tcp.port: 9300
http.port: 9200
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.20.1.4:9300", "10.20.1.5:9300"]
```

**In VM2 (10.20.1.5), I have below configuration in elasticsearch.yml file**

```
cluster.name: TestCluster
node.name: "node2"
transport.tcp.port: 9300
http.port: 9200
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.20.1.4:9300", "10.20.1.5:9300"]
```

But with this configuration, when I start elasticsearch instance, both the instances are coming up as an individual master node. They are not forming the cluster as they are unable to discover them.

**I have also tried below variation of zen unicast but none of them are working for me**

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.20.1.4:9200", "10.20.1.5:9200"]
OR
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.20.1.4", "10.20.1.5"]
OR
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["node1", "node2"]
```

Can someone please help me to get this elasticsearch cluster work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the ES server [is bound to localhost by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html), i.e. in your config you can see this `network.bind_host: _local_`

They took that decision to prevent ES clusters from forming with undesired hosts from the outside world.

Instead you should set the following setting on each of your hosts:

```
network.host: 10.20.1.4 # on VM1
```

and

```
network.host: 10.20.1.5 # on VM2
```

Note that setting `network.host` will set both `network.bind_host` and `network.publish_host` to the same IP address.

Comment: Hi Val, Thanks for the quick fix. I was earlier giving network.host as 0.0.0.0 which turned out with the following error failed to send join request to master [{node1}{bOiZbpdvT3Wy5J-B8NFyIA}{10.0.2.15}{10.0.2.15:9300}{master=true}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[node2][10.0.2.15:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested: IllegalStateException[Node [{node2}{oXn2ozOKTu6PsIHnKMzDoA}{10.0.2.15}{10.0.2.15:9300}] not master for join request]; ]

Comment: Hi @Val I am to stuck on this and my network.host is configured good. my problematic log is that can not connect to master node : failed to send join request to master ... [{node1}{String}{Second_String{node_1_ip}{node_1_ip:9300}{‌​master=true}]